# Jenkins: SmokeTest answer success, but 1 Test is failure

Tags: jenkins

We have in our System SmokeTests on Jenkins. In the log, I see:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 170, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 17
```

Jenkins give it out as successful. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the oroblem. The instance of the jenkins had not enogh memory to catch all. So i reduced the debugmode to write less informations. Know it run without a problem